# Extract Track Information from the uploaded song

Tags: php

I would like to extract some of the information of the uploaded `.mp3` files like artist, album, and album art and use it to store them in database and also extract the album art and save it on a separate server folder.

How?

Answer (score 0):

Use the MP3_ID class to read the ID3 tags.

http://pear.php.net/package/MP3_ID

Comment: Well, I checked it, but I see nothing related to author, title, or album art.

Comment: MP3_Id::getTag('title')? Did you try it?

Comment: I just went through the website, haven't tried it acutally. And what about the Album Art

Comment: Can you combine all the resources you provide into one answer. And do you anything which could extract the album art from the track.

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mp3-lib/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: No. "Use this library" was the answer, not "read something at this page for the answer". The link itself is the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sourcerally.net/Scripts/20-PHP-MP3-Class